# I'm trying to implement a function to insert() into an array

Tags: python, list

```
def insertElement(element, position, array):
    last = len(array) - 1
    if position > len(array) or position < 0:
        print("position does not exist")
    else:
        for q in range(len(array)+1, position, -1):
            array[q+1] = array[q]
            print(array)
        last += 1
        array[position] = element
```

Error message:

```
array[q+1] = array[q] IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb don't iterate over an array while changing it.

Comment: You can't create a new list element by assigning to an index. `q+1` is outside the list, so you can't assign to `array[q+1]`.

Comment: Also, `array[q]` doesn't exist on the first iteration, since you start `q` at `len(array)+1` and the last index is `len(array)-1`. Was `+1` a typo?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `last` variable? You never use it.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the list otherwise you would assign to an index that does not exist.
Also, the loop

```
for q in range(len(array)+1, position, -1):
```

should start from `len(array)-2` until `position-1`.

Your code thus becomes:

```
def insertElement(element, position, array):
    last = len(array) - 1
    if position > len(array) or position < 0:
        print("position does not exist")
    else:
        array.append('_')
        for q in range(len(array)-2, position-1, -1):
            array[q+1] = array[q]
        array[position] = element
```

Comment: Didn't realize that came from the original code, I moved my comment.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you cannot do this by assigning to a non-existent list position.  You must use an operation that makes the list larger: `append` or `extend` in some form, which includes the `+` operator.  This is most easily done with slices, such as

```
array = array[:position] + [element] + array[position:]
```